# Dados de variavel global se perdendo Android

Tags: android, singleton

Olá a todos
 Estou criando um aplicativo que ao a pessoa fazer login, o aplicativo traz os dados `Nome`, `Login`, `Senha` e `Foto(a url)` do banco de dados do servidor, e salva esses dados em um `Singleton` para que eles sejam usados em todas as outras `activitys`. Até aí tudo certo, tudo funcionando certinho, mas quando fiz um botão para a pessoa escolher uma foto da galeria e fazer upload dela(tudo isso está funcionando), percebi que se eu demorar um pouco para escolher a foto e ficar esperando na galeria, os dados que eu gravei no `Singleton` 'se perdem' (como se fossem apagados ou sei lá).
 Queria saber se não tem um jeito de gravar esses dados sem que eles 'se percam' quando eu deixar minha aplicação em `background`.
 **Obs: não postei nenhum código pois acredito que não seja necessário, já que não dá nenhum erro nele, e sim os dados que 'desaparecem', acredito que o android de algum modo esteja apagando eles para liberar memória ou coisa assim. Mas se precisar é só pedirem que edito a pergunta e posto o código.**

Comment: Por que você não usa SharedPreferences para guardar essas informações?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugestão para usar em vez de `Singleton` use a classe  [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) do android.

**Exemplo de uso**:

**1.** Nome de suas preferências

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "YourPreferences";
```

**2.** Restaura as preferências

*O segundo parâmetro do método [`getShardePreferenses`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)) é o modo de escrita: as constantes para uso `MODE_PRIVATE`, `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` e `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`*

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**3.** Restaura uma nova instância de `SharedPreferences.Editor` para criar/modificar os valores no objeto `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
```

**4.** Salva uma nova prefêrencia

```
editor.putString("Nome", "valorAqui");
```

**5.** Confirma a gravação dos dados

```
editor.commit();
```

**6.** Para recuperar os dados basta repetir os passos **1 e 2** e a segunte linha:

```
settings.getString("Nome", "");
```

Como você pode armazenar `Strings` também pode armazenar `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double` e `Boolean`.

[Link útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122651/como-usar-o-sharedpreferences-como-classe)

Comment: Parabéns pela explicação Amigo! Surigo apenas explicar  que no passo 2 , o segundo parametro é o modo de escrita, e recomendar o uso das Constantes ( **Context.MODE_PRIVATE, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE e Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE** )

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Obrigado amigo pela dica. Update na resposta!

Comment: Valeu pela resposta vou tentar implementar no meu código.

Comment: Já pedindo desculpas, mas esqueci de citar que a classe que retorna os dados do usuario do banco de dados em json, está rodando numa Thread separada(AsyncTask),  e acho que por causa disso não estou conseguindo usar o getSharedPreferences(). Estou tentado usar o SharedPreferences como uma classe igual no link que voce passou.

Comment: @Bruno você está tentando dar o `getSharedPreferences` dentro da `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Não, vou te explicar a sequencia. Tenho a MainActivtity com os campos para usuário e senha, ao clicar no botão para logar, os dados login e senha são enviados para a classe LoginBackground(que extende AsyncTask) que envia esses dados(no metodo doInBackground) para a classe LoginHttp, o qual envia esses dados para um webservice em php e retorna os dados desse usuario em json, então nessa mesma classe(LoginHttp) eu salvo(tento salvar) os dados no SharedPreferences(criei uma classe SharedUserPreferences  igual no link que você passou), mas não consigo usar o getSharedPreferences().

Comment: @Bruno Você pode melhorar sua classe `SharedUserPreferences` colocando uma propriedade nela do tipo `Context` e no construtor dela receber este `Context` e fazer a devida atribuição a propriedade. Dai nela é só usar assim: `meuContext.getSharedPreferences("",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38389/discussion-between-igor-mello-and-bruno).