# Android - como salvar um texto digitado em uma EditText

Tags: java, android

Quero saber com faço para salvar o texto digitado em uma EditText para usá-lo depois, não sei se é possível , mas talvez salvando o em um arquivo .txt e depois pegar  o texto presente no arquivo.Obrigado!

Comment: Aqui tem duas formas de usar a classe [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) que supre está sua necessidade. Essa [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123246/dados-de-variavel-global-se-perdendo-android/123271#123271) e está [daqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122651/como-usar-o-sharedpreferences-como-classe/122671#122671)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar os  SharedPreferences.

É usado tipo quando você faz login ele salva o nome de usuário e ir atualizando e salvando os valores de nome de usuário.

Use a imaginação...

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=pt-br#WriteSharedPreference